# 回答の編集を、細かく内容に応じて分割したとき、2つの編集が1つにまとめられてしまいます。

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求

回答をより良いものにしたいため、細かく編集を行っています。
この時、変更の内容には、論理的に2つの内容の変更だと思って、2回に分けて書き込みを行いました。
履歴をチェックしやすくすることで、後で戻すとか、差分をチェックしてもらうのが簡単になるだろうと思ったからです。

すると、変更内容のサマリが2つ目の物になり、2つの編集が統合されていました。
これは細かい編集を全て記録しないほうがよいなどの理由による、意図された挙動でしょうか……？
(それか私の使いかたがまずいのかもしれない。その場合はご指摘いただきたく...汗)

またもし、これが狙った挙動である場合の要望なのですが、
2つとも編集が書き込まれていて、かつ、それぞれ編集サマリが異なる場合には
2つの編集として記録するようにできないでしょうか……？
この場合、小さい編集が統合されるなどの挙動は変わらず、
論理的に異なると編集者が判断した編集は記録が残る形になるかと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5分以内に同じユーザーから為された編集は1つにまとめられます。
これは、誤字の修正など、短時間に細かい編集が繰り返されたときに編集履歴の件数が無駄に長くならないようにするための設定で、バグではありません。

git におけるコミットのように編集を意図的に分割したいお気持ちは分かりますが、論理単位で編集を分けたとしてどのようなメリットがあるのかすぐには思いつかないなと思いました。

参考: [Is there a grace period for correction of edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20441/341401)

Comment: ありがとうございます！そのドキュメントを読んで少し考えてみます

Comment: 改めて何を考えていたのか整理してみました。
1つには、私個人として「編集サマリの記述が嘘になる」のを気にしていることに気づきました。
書かない選択が普通である以上、あまり意味は無いのかもしれないのですが、サマリを書くという形式であるため、編集履歴1つ分の意味を気にしているところがあります。それが纏められているので気になってしまうのだと思いました。
これはあまり気にしなければ"それはそれ"ということになると思うので、この質問は閉じてしまおうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 僕は編集サマリに複数の内容を書くことがよくあるので、そのまま複数書いてしまえば良いのだと思います (たとえば「タグを編集しました。コード部分を装飾しました。」みたいな感じです :)

Comment: なるほど！その手は考えてなかったです

Answer (score 2):

誤字脱字の間違いや改善を目的とした編集は適時行うこと自体は問題ありませんが、編集するからにはその編集1回でベストの状態にするべきなのかなと思っています。

ロールバックはあくまで**元の投稿の意図が失われてしまった**状態などからの復旧を目的としていて、git(GitHub)のようにいつでも戻すことを前提とした履歴付けを意識するのは少し違うかなと。

参考：
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

> 他の人が推奨した編集が良くない場合は、投稿を以前のバージョンにロール バックすることも可能です。

Comment: なるほどですね。あんまり分割すること自体が推奨されない感じなんですね。